# phonegap navigator.notification.alert

Tags: cordova, notifications, xcode4.5

I am using xcode 4.5 and cordova 2.1.0 and have a couple alerts showing using:

```
function showAlert(message)    {
navigator.notification.alert(
                             message,               // message
                             alertDismissed,
                             'My App',   // title
                             'close'                // buttonName
                             );
```

}

All is working well, however, when my app posts to Facebook and Twitter, the success callbacks fire the showAlert above, this results in the alerts firing at the same time and doesn't look  nice and smooth. Is there a way to queue them up so only one fires and when the user closes the first window, the next one fires?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.when function in jQuery or use a timer with an fade effect. This should look nice and smooth ;-)

Example for when():

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Example for an effect timer:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's been a bit of confusion. I don't have an issue with the animation of the alert, the problem is the 2 alerts firing at the same time